# Plugin for styling Forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a Jquery plugin that i can use to decorate the forms elements. Form should works even if JavaScript is disabled. I want to style Radio, check-box, select, buttons, file uploads Inputs. Also scroll-bars support

I know jquery ui supports the last 2 and i also know i can use css for buttons. But is there any that allows styling of these elements. I also know version 2 of UI plans to provide this but till then what.

Comment: why do you want jQuery to style forms elements? Isn't it what we have CSS for?

Comment: if css would have supported it i might have asked how can i do it in css